# Use Backbone.history.navigate to the same route but without any get params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, browser-history

I was able to use Backbone's history.navigate to change my url silently. Like from `/itmes` to `/itmes?price=5` or whatever

But when I want to change it back(like I cleared some filters), from `/items?price=5` to `/items`, it doesn't do the job.

Example code:

```
# From /items to /items?price=5&category=business, works
Backbone.history.navigate("/items?price=5&category=business", false)
# From /items?price=5&category=business to /item, doesn't work as I've expected
Backbone.history.navigate("/items", false) # this one doesn't
```

Any ideas? If Backbone's history doesn't support this feature, can somebody show me a solution? Much appreciated.

**More info:**
I found another weird thing. Let's say we are at `/items?price=5`, if I call `Backbone.history.navigate("/items", false)` directly. Nothing happens.

But if I do a `Backbone.history.navigate("/items?price=5", false)`, and then, call `Backbone.history.navigate("/items", false)`, it does the job and go to `/items` correctly.'

The problem of this ways is it messed up the history, there will be an addition node between the normal history.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/TXBn9/ - are you using pushState?

Comment: @fencliff Yes pushState is enabled. Maybe that's the problem.